# Error occurred while installing Cassandra "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap"

Tags: cmd, cassandra, jvm, heap-memory

I was trying to run cassandra thru command line

```
{C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-cassandra-3.11.11\bin>cassandra}
```

WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable.
Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

RAM - 16 GB

Due to above problem, I have tried running java with runtime paramter -Xms3G, still cassandra is not running.

Request some help, how to solve this issue? Let me know if any other details required.

Answer (score 1):

### Heap size

This error indicates that you don't have enough free memory on your machine:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Shutdown other apps you don't need to free up some memory then try to start Cassandra with a more conservative allocation of 1GB for max heap size and 400MB for NewGen by uncommenting the following lines in the "Heap Settings" section of conf/jvm.options:

```
-Xms1G
-Xmx1G
-Xmn400M
```

### Powershell permissions

You need to grant Powershell permissions to the Windows account running the Cassandra script.

You can grant permissions to all Windows accounts on your machine with:

```
C:\> powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

WARNING: You need to run the command prompt as an administrator for the command above to work.

As an alternative, you can grant unrestricted access just for your current user with:

```
C:\> powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
```

### Windows support

I wanted to let you know that there is very limited Windows support in Cassandra 3.11 and there are several known issues that will not be fixed due to limitations in the operating system.

Furthermore, Windows support has been completely dropped in Cassandra 4.0 due to lack of maintainers and testing ([CASSANDRA-16171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16171)).

As a workaround, we recommend the following:

- [Deploy Cassandra in Docker](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html)
- Deploy Cassandra in a VM using software like VirtualBox
- Deploy [K8ssandra.io](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05)

If you just want to build apps with Cassandra as a backend, [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/3jdZVbU) has a free tier that lets you launch a Cassandra cluster in a few clicks with no credit card required. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Its clear how to approach.

Comment: thanks, it was useful. Actually I have taken your suggestion to  go with astra DB for my project.

Comment: I have already given my response accepting it, since my reputation(score-11) is low, it is not being reflected here. Thanks.